# Можно ли так сделать на css?

Tags: css

Можно ли такое градиентом сделать?
Пример нашел, но что-то не выходит пока
http://dabblet.com/gist/1457668
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
div {  
  background: radial-gradient(circle, black 10%, transparent 10%), radial-gradient(circle, black 10%, white 10%) 5px 4px;
  background-size: 11px 10px;
}

html,
body,
div {
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Леночка а что у вас в сниппете ? а то у меня не фига ни чего нету

Comment: CSS: `div {  
  background: radial-gradient(circle, black 10%, transparent 10%), radial-gradient(circle, black 10%, white 10%) 5px 4px;
  background-size: 11px 10px;
}

html,
body,
div {
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  width: 100px;
}`

HTML:

`<div></div>`

Comment: Я тут без префиксов, на быструю руку, возможно из-за этого не везде отображается.

Comment: Да да , понял , как обычно + вам

Comment: Спасибо! =)))))